# Hide input files during the conversion of python scripts into exe

Tags: python-3.x, input, exe, cx-freeze

I have python scripts in folder A and some dependent input files (.xlsx,.txt) in folder B.
I am using cx_Freeze to convert them into exe.
I have the files in the folder B as a list in include_files in `setup.py`
During the conversion, the files fall in the build folder.
The files should not be visible to the user, or at least they should be only in read-only mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [os.chmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod) at the end of your setup script to make any file of the build directory read-only. For example:

```
import os
import stat
os.chmod(path_to_file, stat.S_IREAD)
```

Of course you need to know the path to the build directory. You can also tell cx_Freeze which directory to use as build directory by using the `build_exe` option of the `build_exe`command, see the [cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe).

Comment: Thanks !. Actually i previously tried this. But i used this command in my main script instead of setup script.