# Hide input json files during the conversion of python scripts into exe

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I am making a console app to download gcp objects using service account GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS, which is stored in json file. When i buddle my project using auto-py-to-exe to make it as an exe file. The json file comes into this folder. I want to hide this file from user. Is there any way to do so??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.chmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod) at the end of your setup script to make any file of the build directory read-only. For example:

```
import os
import stat
os.chmod(path_to_file, stat.S_IREAD)
```

And also to hide use  below   :

`stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` this indicates The file or directory is hidden. It is not included in an ordinary directory listing. Refer this [Link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.S_IRWXU) how to use file attribute Hidden.

Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58025136/19230181) for more information

Comment: It shouldn't be a read-only file. It should be hidden. how to hide file using this "stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN" method. After hiding it is it possible to authenticate with gcp.

Comment: Refer this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) for more information